# How to open Sketch in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, latex

I recently installed sketch (UI Design Software) on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. It's showing 'installed' but I am  unable to open it. When I search sketch in search box nothing comes.

Comment: Might be database which hasn't updated. Have you tried logging out and back in?

Comment: Could you give link of that software or how you tried installing it?

Comment: How did you (try to) install Sketch? Did you follow some sort of instructions published online?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit1: add one more workaround...

You installed the TeX 3d graphic library[1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/sketch), not the **macOS ONLY** sketch design tool [2](https://www.sketchapp.com/)

Sorry this app is only in Mac OS, no windows (so no wine), no Linux port.

Workaround:

1. Ask for exported files(PDF recommended)
2. Try marvelapp.com
3. Try (14 days trial) or Pay for avocode.com
4. Use a macOS machine

Comment: Using Figma (free for at least 1 project) you can open Sketch files from the browser too.